# How to center these 3 drop-down menus

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to center these 3 drop downs only using html.‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎ ‏‏‎ ‎

I tried this code here thinking it would it would be in the center nice and even:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  float: left;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Mega Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button>Prozys</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Submenu item 1</a>
      <a href="#">Submenu item 2</a>
      <a href="#">Submenu item 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button>Games</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Submenu item 1</a>
      <a href="#">Submenu item 2</a>
      <a href="#">Submenu item 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button>AI</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Submenu item 1</a>
      <a href="#">Submenu item 2</a>
      <a href="#">Submenu item 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="showFrame()">Open iFrame</button>
  <iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame"></iframe>
```

But the boxes are a little off/uneven . When searching I couldn’t find any thing that helped with the problem I am having.